# How to LOAD csv file with extra empty row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the CSV file which I need to load to mysql database. Problem is that every row of data is followed by empty row:

```
open_test_uuid|open_uuid|asn|bytes_download
     
O0037c645-0c7b-4bd0-a6dc-1983e6d0f814|Pf13e1f22-92f6-4a49-9bd3-2882373d0266|25255|11704458 

O0037c645-0c7b-4bd0-a6dc-1983e6d0f814|Pf13e1f22-92f6-4a49-9bd3-2882373d0266|25255|11704458
```

I tried differend combinations of LOAD command but nothing works.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/BauchMAC/Desktop/details_201301.csv'
INTO TABLE netztest
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'  <--HERE should be some magic line 
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I have no idea how to solve that...
Thank you for every idea

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\n'
```

or

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n\r\n'
```

and if that doesn't work you could pre-process the file before feed it to MySQL.
If you're on linux you could run this:

```
cat file.csv | grep -v '^\s*$' > fixed.csv
```

**UPDATE**

Perhaps a little Perl will do the trick:

```
perl -e '$_=`cat file.csv`; s/[\r\n]+/\n/g; print'
```

Comment: I've tried the terminal command but it returns "binary files fixed.csv matches" I did some research I tried to add "-a" but it returns me just first row...

Comment: I just noticed the path and you're probably on Windows, right? You could try fixing the file with an editor - it shouldn't be a binary - but that's probably cumbersome. How is the CSV file created?

Comment: no,  I am on Mac. It was originaly json data format but some guy changed the format to csv with python

Comment: according to the iternet it should work, but when I try your script or any other without "-a" I just get the "new_file.csv" which is filled with "Binary file new_file.csv matches"

Comment: It could be that there is a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning though that shouldn't make grep think it is a binary file. In any case, I added a Perl oneliner that should get the job done.